# React app on Firebase: New deployment not showing (old deployment cached in browser)

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I created a react app using `create-react-app` and deployed it to Firebase as such:

`npm run build && firebase deploy`

It deploys fine.
The issue is that following deploy, the previous version of the app continues to show on the browser - as if the browser is caching the whole app.

I saw this thread about this issue:
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1910

I literally need to reset the caching on the browser to get the new version of the app.
Is there a way to disable the browser caching of the app with the React app or Firebase console, or at least to ensure that the latest deployment is displayed?

Comment: I solved this adding 
`"headers": [{"source": "/service-worker.js", "headers": [{"key": "Cache-Control", "value": "no-cache"}]}]`

to firebase.json under hosting property as explain [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#firebase).

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer to my questions here:

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#opting-out-of-caching

The problem is specific to React.js and NOT to Firebase.

> Opting Out of Caching If you would prefer not to enable service
>   workers prior to your initial production deployment, then remove the
>   call to registerServiceWorker() from src/index.js.
>
> If you had previously enabled service workers in your production
>   deployment and have decided that you would like to disable them for
>   all your existing users, you can swap out the call to
>   registerServiceWorker() in src/index.js first by modifying the service
>   worker import:
>
> import { unregister } from './registerServiceWorker'; and then call
>   unregister() instead. After the user visits a page that has
>   unregister(), the service worker will be uninstalled. Note that
>   depending on how /service-worker.js is served, it may take up to 24
>   hours for the cache to be invalidated.